# Haproxy cant bind [0.0.0.0:80] - CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, apache, centos, haproxy

im running on CentOS 6.5 and actually trying to follow this tutorial (http://socketo.me/docs/deploy) on Websocket which says that I need to install Haproxy and run the following linux command :

```
sudo haproxy -f /etc/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -D
```

The problem is that I get this message :

```
[ALERT] 015/013939 (22640) : Starting frontend public: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:80]
```

My "netstat -nat | grep 80 | grep LISTEN" returns :

```
tcp        0      0 212.227.96.81:80            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8880                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 2001:8d8:86c:6e00::14:3b:80 :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::8880                     :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::7080                     :::*                        LISTEN
```

PS : 212.227.96.81 is the IP adress that pings on my domain name.
What should I do exactly to resolve this ? Is it apache ? Because I restarted it and nothing.
Thank you.

Comment: You have to shut down Apache. You can't have `haproxy` and `apache` both serving port 80.

Comment: You run haproxy on the load balancer, and apache on the web servers behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your web server is listing on port 80

```
tcp        0      0 212.227.96.81:80            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

you need to change the Apache/webserver port to a different one. you can't bind haproxy and Apache on the same port on the same server

```
client send request to port 80 ---> HA-PROXY--->send request to apache (port 8080).
```

asssuming both running on the same server.

Comment: I figured out that was NGINX who was listenning to 80, and that as you just said couldnt bind them both on the same port, so what will you advice me to make them both work ? (Thank you)

Comment: Just change the ha-proxy to a port 80, because clients are connecting to http port 80, and change nginx to a different port like 8080 , and then configure your ha-proxy to send request  (pipe client request) to your nginx port 8080.

Comment: Actually Im a web developer and I know just a little few things on server commands, if you can tell me the commands to type that would be perfect, thank you so much, dont mind if you need me to display you anything that can help.

Comment: stop nginx ( /etc/rc.d/init.d/ngix stop, then open change /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and change from listen 80 to  listen  8080; start nginx (/etc/rc.d/init.d/nginx start),/etc/haproxy.cfg and change frontend http  
  
   bind 0.0.0.0:80   then restart ha-proxy. then you need to configure your ha-proxy to connect to your web server. not sure what kind of a config you are using, you can try this url http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2011/02/26/haproxy-quickstart-w-full-example-config-file.html